# Android: Play video from file buffer

Tags: android, video, buffer

Is there a way to play/load a video from a file buffer?
I have video's that are encrypted and only get decrypted before being played. I currently have a load screen to indicate the movie is being loaded while it is being decrypted. This takes around 1 second per megabyte. I was wondering if I can take the bytes that are being decrypted and push them to the video player so it can play while the video is being decrypted.  the videos are mp4's

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But you need to implement a streaming scheme. You need two main components: a streaming server such as a local http instance and javax.crypto.CipherInputStream. For example, it's the architecture used in LocalSingleHttpServer of libmedia.

Comment: But is this approach safe? What if some uses a network profiler app (Like fiddler for windows) and capture all local network calls. The user will able to get hold of decrypted bytes as they flow between the streaming server and the player and save it locally in a file?

Comment: Your question has sense but is out of the context: you should read that the server and the encrypted file are both hosted into the Android device, with the player.

Comment: @libeasy I'm pretty sure Katrik wasn't saying "literally use a proxy or something and see traffic over the network" - he was more saying "what if they monitor local network traffic on the android device" which I would think may well be possible.

Comment: Hello, @libeasy your library is not available in xamarin. but I want to do same thing. Now what I do is decrypt entire video once and then play but it takes so much time for large videos. do you have any sample to implement this local http server in device ? please help.